# Javascript Function That Selects Check Box List and then clicks li Button to complete popup window

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I need recursive JavaScript function that selects a check box list, then clicks a button and finally clicks another button to complete an action.

see the capture pictures

[image]

[image]

the check class name is (checkboxes), the li button is (liBtn), and the modal complete button is (btn-success)

briefly i created this function

```
function automation() {
    let chBox = document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes");
    for (var i = 0; i < chBox.length; i++) {
        let chBox = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes');
        chBox.forEach (btn => btn.click());
        let btnElem = document.querySelector('li#Li3');
        btnElem.click();
       }
}
```

but returns this error

```
VM162:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at automation (<anonymous>:7:21)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Along with javascript, add your html code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would need a bit more information on the problem to be more helpful.

I may be misunderstanding, but I don't think you need to have the list items clicked recursively.

This is because since the document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes') selects all the checkboxes of that class, and so it will click all of them (see 1st snippet below).

The button error is probably from the querySelector no finding a target, which means you might have the wrong CSS attributes trying to select that element (see 2nd snippet below).

```js
function automation() {
      let chBox = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes');
      chBox.forEach (btn => btn.click());
      let btnElem = document.querySelector('li#Li3');
      btnElem.click();
};

automation();


// demostrates click works
let btnElem = document.querySelector('li#Li3');
btnElem.addEventListener('click', () => alert('button clicked'));
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' />
  <input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' />
  <input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<hr />
<div class='container'>
  <input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' />
  <input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' />
  <input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<hr />
<li id='Li3'>button</li>
```

```js
   function clickNoElement() {
       let btnElem = document.querySelector('li#WrongId');
       btnElem.click();
    }

clickNoElement();
```

```html
 <li type='button' id='ActuallyId'>Button</li>
```